# Identify a process that uploads data

Tags: network, windows

I am using the tool "Internet Traffic Agent" to monitor my in- and outbound traffic. It shows me clearly that over a period of approx. an hour, some process on my machine is uploading data, about 200–250MB. This seems to me very suspicious.

I have noticed that a data is constantly sent to 255.255.255.255. Is that OK?

In general, how can identify all processes that are sending some kind of data over Internet on Windows 7?

Comment: Could it be a key logger with video monitoring ??
Have you tried to scan your Pc for malicious apps ?

Comment: I have tried with "Spybot" (available as a portable app) and scanned my machine with "Avast" anti-virus. There were no any high level threats - only a few tracing cookies. Can you recommend any valuable software tool scanning for such malicious applications?

Comment: This question has already been discussed at http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20027/how-to-check-if-someone-is-in-my-computer/20043#20043

Comment: @AliAhmad: I've used netstat -oa to list all active connection and the PIDs of the services related but I am still not unable to identify the meaning of sending data to 255.255.255.255. In the result list of the command, there is no any entry for the address 255.255.255.255.

Comment: @jilt3d: 255.255.255.255 is a broadcast address and when something is send on this address it is received by all the devices on a same network. Secondly routers are configured to block broadcast traffic.

Comment: I think troubleshooting your network configurations may resolve the problem.

Comment: @AliAhmad: actually that was the initial issue. I was constantly disconnected from my Internet connection and I was troubleshooting each time, but nothing helps. My Internet provider told me that they registered a large amount of upload traffic (around 2GB for a day) which causes some kind of bandwidth throttling and this may be the reason behind the constantly dropping connection.

Comment: @jilt3d:It will be helpful if you can generate network traffic networks logs with  wireshark or tcpdump. Analyzing traffic logs may reveal uplink traffic you are interested in.

Answer (score 3):

You could try to use Sysinternal's [Portmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896644.aspx) to see which process(es) broadcasts on 255.255.255.255. Don't be too alarmed before you see what kind of things are broadcasted.

To see a more precise view of the packets sent/received, use : [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/).

Comment: I am not able to use "Portmon" under Windows 7 - I followed the instructions to run it on non-network disk with administrator privileges but capture can not be started.

Comment: "wireshark" provides a lot of information - more than I need I guess, and it seems it will be harder for me to extract the valuable one. Think, it will be easier and more reliable solution to re-install my OS to get rid off any potential harmful applications installed on my machine. I will play a bit more with these tools, and if there is any progress I will update the thread.

Comment: It is probably wiser indeed. However, you can "filter" things with Wireshark, but you should probably ask your local nerd to have a look at it, or spend quite a lot of time in search engines or reading its documentation... I could help with specific questions. To get you started with wireshark: on top, there is a "filter" you can use to filter down the packets: enter in it "ip.dst==255.255.255.255" and you'll see packets sent to this destination (note however that there are more broadcast adresses, the others depending on your local network configuration) (and many legit broadcasts)

Comment: Well, I did a factory restore to the system from a special partition, just to be on the safe side and get rid of any potential malwares, but now I am getting a strange error at the Windows 7 startup. Here you may want to check the details: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26115/multiple-running-instances-of-rundll32-exe

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the built-in Windows 7 functionality.

Bring up your task manager by pressing **ctrl + shift + esc** then click the **Performance** tab. From there you will see a **Resource Monitor** button towards the bottom. Click that and then click the **Network** tab on the new window that opens.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to debug some of your installed applications generating broadcast traffic.You can compute your broadcast address by replacing all the host bits with 1s i.e If your network is 192.168.1.0/24, then your network address will be 192.168.1.0 and your broadcast address will be 192.168.1.255. 255.255.255.255 is physical layer broadcast address and 192.168.1.0/24 is a network layer broadcast address. You need to identify application using your network layer broadcast address not physical broadcast address.