# Multiple "rundll32.exe mhunk.dme" instances. Is my PC Infected with Something?

Tags: windows

So, I have this strange list of rundll32.exe
There are quite a lot of rows of it (see attached image) when I open the process tab in my task manager

I've already read the link here: [Multiple running instances of rundll32.exe](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26115/multiple-running-instances-of-rundll32-exe)

The patterns appeared to be in the cmd line column

> rundll32.exe mhunkw.dme,

For example, in my screenshot you will see

> rundll32.exe mhunkw.dme,krvvjwa
>
> rundll32.exe mhunkw.dme,oxvlyk
>
> ...
>
> rundll32.exe mhunkw.dme,szswzunt

the list goes on.
Any idea what this is?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple copies of rundll32 running strangely named files does look like a classic malware infection to me, although as the article you linked to states there could be benign reasons, and gives steps to possibly determine what these files are. You could also use [this link's](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/multiple-rundll32-process-running-in-taskmanager/f3bd5087-a690-4fd8-b0d5-1400e9152866) suggestions to try and recover your system.

Using a malware removal tool may tell you what you've been infected with. Realistically though even if a malware removal tool seems to work you cannot be sure it's been successful - some malware is incredibly persistent and you can sink a lot of time trying to clean it off a system with no success. This is why the general advice on this site is to save your data, wipe your system, and restore your data and programs.

Also, keep your system updated in the future. The majority of malware out there uses well known security holes that have been patched for weeks or months, and uses flaws on not just the OS but Java, Adobe Flash, and such-like. So keep all your software up to date, not just Windows.